# How do I show $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{x}{\ln(x)} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to (roughly) plot the graph of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\ln(x)}; x > 0$ by hand, and I was able to show this much so far:

- $\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x) = +\infty$
- $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) = -\infty$
- $f$ has a minimum at $x = e$, with $f(e) = e$.
- $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = +\infty$ (using L'Hôpital's
  rule).

The only piece remaining is seeing what happens to $f$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ with $x > 0$, i.e., evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)$. I can see that this limit is $0$, but is there an easy of showing this (this is from a calculus lecture, so I don't want to resort to $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs)?

Comment: What is $0/-\infty$?

Comment: @Zenix: Isn't it an indeterminate form?

Comment: You got probably confused with $\infty /\infty$ or $0/0$.

Comment: @TrainHeartnet No, it isn't. We can't use l'Hospital with that expression.

Comment: Oh, I see! I thought $\frac{0}{\infty}$ was also an indeterminate form, just one that can't be evaluated using L'Hôpital's rule. Thanks for clearing this for me, @DonAntonio and @Zenix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac x{\log x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac1{\log x}\cdot x\right)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1{\log x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0^+} x=0\cdot 0=0$$

by arithmetic of limits